# How can I change the color of rectangle?

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to change the color of button background and I did it. Now I want to change the color of rectangle below the images and color of button sides but it doesn't work. I tried a number of things but still I could not find a solution yet. Any suggestions?

```xml
<Window.Resources>
        <sys1:String x:Key="currentDate">
            10.09.2019
        </sys1:String>
        <Style x:Key="topLeft" TargetType="Panel">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="MidnightBlue"/>

        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="whiteTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="leftButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border CornerRadius="5"
                                Margin="5"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                >

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Height="30"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="redBrush" Fill="Black" Height="5"/>

                             </StackPanel>
                                <ContentPresenter 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            **<Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).Color"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                To="White"/>
                                <ColorAnimation 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).Color"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                To="Red"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).Color"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                To="{x:Null}"/>
                                <ColorAnimation 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).Color"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                To="{x:Null}"/>**


                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the border color you can use [How to change the border color of a flat button style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837816/how-to-change-the-border-color-of-a-flat-button-style)
:

```
<Border BorderBrush="YOURCOLOR" BorderThickness="2"></Border>
```

And to color your rectangle [How do you color a rectangle in C# that has been declared in XAML in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886537/how-do-you-color-a-rectangle-in-c-sharp-that-has-been-declared-in-xaml-in-wpf):

```
myRectangle.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.YOURCOLOR
```

Comment: Thank you.It worked for border but I'm still stuck with Rectangle.

Comment: Please, can you update your code and explain what doesn't work/what have you tried/what error do you have?

Comment: I did it.When I wrote this code in controlTemplate ıt fixed.

Comment: Yes, it is the right place to write it.So it is all ok? If yes, remember to mark this as solution(and an upvote is use to say thank you in here :) )